# Convert string to bigdecimal in android

Tags: java, android, string, converters, bigdecimal

Hi How can i convert string to bigdecimal in android.

This is my 1st activity:

```
public class ViewCartActivity extends Activity {

String mGrandTotal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewcartactivity);

    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TextView mTxtViewGrandTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewGrandTotalValue);
    Button mBtnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);

    ViewCartAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new ViewCartAdapter(
            ViewCartActivity.this);

    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

    if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() > 0) {
        Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0)
                .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL));
        for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) {
            mGTotal = mGTotal
                    + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(
                            SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL));
        }

        mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText("$" + mGrandTotal);
    }

    mBtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerLogin.class);
            i.putExtra("GrandTotal", mGrandTotal);
                startActivity(i);

        }
```

The CustomerLogin.java(next activity):

```
      String mGrandTotal;
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.customer_login);
       Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

         String total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
         -----
       ------
           if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
              {
            String s= getIntent().getStringExtra(mGrandTotal);
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(mGrandTotal, s);

           startActivity(intent);

              }
```

The PayPalIntegrationActivity.java(3rd activity) look like:

```
public class PayPalIntegrationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 String mGrandTotal;
    private PayPal mPayPal;
   private CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal_integration);
       -------
        ------
          @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            payWithPaypal();
        }


         private PayPalPayment  payWithPaypal() {
                PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String total = in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal);
                BigDecimal sPrice = new BigDecimal(total);

        newPayment.setSubtotal(sPrice);
        newPayment.setCurrencyType(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));
```

I have to pass the grandtotal value to my paypalintegration activity.

But my console window shows following error:

```
      12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782): java.lang.NullPointerException
       12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782):   at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:483)
      12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782):    at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.PayPalIntegrationActivity.payWithPaypal(PayPalIntegrationActivity.java:74)
        12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.PayPalIntegrationActivity.onClick(PayPalIntegrationActivity.java:66)
      12-21 05:52:09.571: E/AndroidRuntime(782):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
```

please help me.whats wrong in my code.

`I wish to need the o/p` is:

mGrandTotal value is pass from my 1st activity to last activity(paypalintegration activity)

mGrandTotal value is set to   below line: newPayment.setSubtotal(sPrice);

How can i do.please let me know

Comment: How do you expect `BigDecimal` to convert your string `"total"` into some numeric value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not getting error because  of  converting String to Bigdecimal as there is an Constructor of Bigdecimal for the same 
                     **BigDecimal(String val)** 
,you are getting error due to **total** has **null** value and it can not  be converted to BigDecimal. you can do like this

```
      String total="0.0";
      if(in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal)!=null && !in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal).isEmpty()){
            total=in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal);
      }
       BigDecimal sPrice = new BigDecimal(total);
```

hope this will work for u...!!!

Comment: i got  The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type 
  String these error.my  " Compiler compliance level as 1.6.how can i clear these error

Comment: use **!in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal).equals("")** instead of **!in.getStringExtra(mGrandTotal).isEmpty()**,if it will work vote up for my answer..!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are attempting to convert a non numeric string `total` to a BigDecimal number. Assign some numeric values to `KEY_TOTAL` e.g.

```
          static final String KEY_TOTAL = "0.0";//some numeric value here
```

Comment: dynamically added total value from xml parsing.thats why i don't have write the numaric value directly.I have getting 
static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total"; these from my previous activity.how can i add the total value is set to  newPayment.setSubtotal(sPrice);please help me

Comment: @user1897014 Above answer was against your previous post.  Now I bet that this statement `String total = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TOTAL);` is not getting the String value and `total` is assigned with `null` and hence the issue.

Comment: please see my updated question and give me solution for these.

Comment: Yes am getting null value only.how can i pass mGrandTotal value  from my 1st activity to last activity(paypalintegration activity)

mGrandTotal value is set to below line: newPayment.setSubtotal(sPrice);
please help me